# Populate Form in JSP page from Java

Tags: java, html, ajax, spring, jsp

Im trying to find a way of populating a 'Form' within a JSP page based on a result from Java.

So here is my Javascript code:

```
$('#uSystemList').change(function() {
    $.get("/live-application/systemById", {systemid: $("#uSystemList").val()}, displayChangedSystemResults, "html");
});

function displayChangedSystemResults(html){
    $('#systemForm').empty();
    $('#systemForm').append(html);
}
```

The Form:

```
<form:form id="systemForm" method="post" action="/live-application/systemSave" commandName="systemForm">
<tr>
    <td valign="top"><form:select path="uSystemList" id="uSystemList"> </form:select> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top"><form:input path="fSystemName"/></td>
</tr>
</form:form>
```

And the Java side:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/systemById", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getSystemById(@RequestParam("systemid") String systemid, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder refreshHtml = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        String html = new String();
        if (!systemid.equals("")) {
            System system = service.getSystemById(systemid));

            html = html + "<input type='text' value='" + system.getName() + "' id='fSystemName' />";
        } 
        refreshHtml.append(hostHtml);
        outputStream.write(refreshHtml.toString().getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        outputStream.flush();
    }
}
```

As a test I just want to populate the `fSystemName` field of the form but nothing happens when it returns to the `displayChangedSystemResults` function. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `form:select` maybe should end on `>` and for `form:input` there is a missing `/>`

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake as I stripped quite alot of code out of it. I will edit now...

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way to achieve is to set the values you want to display Request Attribute 
and access it in JSP .

**in Server Side**

Adapt the method signature to include Spring model

```
public void getSystemById(@RequestParam("systemid") String systemid, Model model , OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
```

**And in the request handling method you can do**

```
System system = service.getSystemById(systemid));
model.addAttribute("fSystemName", system.getName());
```

**And then display it in JSP  using JST lib**

In order to use JSTL add the following jars to your `/WEB-INF/lib`

- [jsf-api.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jsp-api/2.0/jsp-api-2.0.jar)
- [jstl.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar)

**Edit**

---

```
    <tr>
 <td valign="top"><input type="text" value="${fSystemName}"></input></td>
    </tr>
```

**Edit 2**

You should not directly handle the outputstream, and you should let spring do it for you.
Your method should ideally return a `view name` , which spring will automatically resolve

Check this below simple tutorial. This should put you in the right direction

[Spring 3 MVC Hellow World](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it just says 'Tag (form:input) must be empty' on the JSP side

Comment: Thanks - still nothing is happening. Do I need to do something with the model e.g. return it? you have the method return type as void so I assume not but please let me know if there is something i need to do in order to get it to 'refresh'?

Comment: I did check the edit, but it still doesn't set the system name field...any ideas?